# get info from page using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

in a page there is some tags like this:

```
<tr class=" ev_modern">
 <td align="left" valign="middle" title="1">1</td>
 <td align="left" valign="middle" title="09:00:08" class="">09:00:08</td>
 <td align="left" valign="middle">3000</td>
 <td align="left" valign="middle" title="2539.00">2539.00</td>
</tr>
```

I looking for(row number, time, number1, number2) each of them, and tried many ways but I couldn't, one of them:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[class=' ev_modern']"));
```

> elements is empty

how get information by selenium using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css selector to get to the `td` elements:

```
By.CssSelector("[class=' ev_modern'] td")
```

Then you can iterate through the list of elements.

Or if you want to get text from first row, do following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class=' ev_modern'] td:nth-child(1)")).Text;
```

Hope this helps.